# QT: Passing QDialog as a object

Tags: qt, qobject

I am new to QT. I have several QDialogs in my QT project. I have created a generic class to change the properties of widgets inside QDialogs. My generic class has a **static** method which will change the properties of widgets.

```
void MyClass::setFontsizeToWidgets(float modValue, QObject obj)
{
    QFont f;
    float pointSize = 0.0;

    QList<QPushButton*> buttons = obj.findChildren<QPushButton*>();

    foreach ( QPushButton * button, buttons)
    {
        f = button->font();
        pointSize = f.pointSizeF();
        f.setPointSizeF(pointSize*modValue);
        button->setFont(f);
    }
}
```

Now my questions is, how to pass the QDialog as a object to the above static method from QDialog class? So that the static method will change the font size of the QPushButton(s) in the QDialog.

Comment: You probably want `obj` to be a reference or a pointer: `void MyClass::setFontsizeToWidgets(float modValue, QObject *obj)`.

Comment: That is ok. But when calling this method from QDialog class, how to pass QDialog as a object of QObject?

Comment: Pass "this". A QDialog is a QWidget is a QObject. So you can pass a QDialog* as QObject*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
void MyClass::setFontsizeToWidgets(float modValue, QObject *obj)
{
    //do something 
}

void MyDialog::someFunction() //this is a function of your QDialog class
{
    MyClass::setFontsizeToWidgets(10, this);
}
```